# How to make metasploit backdoor persistent in Android?

Tags: android, metasploit, backdoor

I created a payload with msfvenom and installed it on Android smartphone, but after a reboot or long time without use, it stops working, because the OS kills the process.

Is there any way to associate it with any permanent service? I saw that in newer versions of Android this is only possible with a notification bar, which for me would not be a problem, after all is for my personal use and is not "hidden" but I need some help regarding the persistence of the backdoor.

Comment: (https://www.yeahhub.com/persistent-backdoor-android-using-kali-linux-shell-script/) Doesnt this work?

Comment: @VipulNair Unfortunately not, after rebooting the script stops executing and the payload dies